# Understanding data abstraction levels

Tags: database-design, terminology, database-theory

The three-level ANSI SPARC Database Architecture suggests three data abstraction levels, namely, *external*, *conceptual*, and *internal* levels.

If I understand correctly, the *external* level represents the users' views, the *conceptual* level is the conceptual diagram (ER model), and the *internal* level is the relational model.

My problem is that I found in the literature that besides those, there is a fourth level (the lowest one), which is the *physical* level.

I want to understand what is it concretely? Is it at this point that we define the type of index, access paths, and things related to physical access to data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the definitions of the schemas or levels of representation of the ANSI/SPARC architecture did not reach the desired precision, they are *only* three, and they are named *external*, *conceptual* and *internal*, respectively.

As far as I know, there is no fourth level, because the physical structures employed by a database management system (DBMS for brevity) compose, in fact, the internal schema, as I will explain below.

<sub>*Note*: Even if imprecise, the ANSI/SPARC architecture is definitely a very useful reference when building a system, so it looks like the literature you found contains inaccurate information or perhaps it makes a reference to the (also very useful) notion where the layers of abstraction of a database are called *conceptual*, *logical* and *physical*, which has different implications.</sub>

**Brief descriptions of the three ANSI/SPARC levels**

I deem opportune to describe each level (ordered from the highest to the lowest degree of abstraction) so as to expose its scope:

- The *external* level is the way in which the information is presented to end-users of a computerized information system; e.g., the specific organization of the pieces of information as displayed or requested in the screens or windows (via, e.g, lists, grids, labels, text boxes, check boxes, drop-down menus, etc.) of an application program.
- The *conceptual* level involves the representation of the structure of the information as (a) perceived by the business experts and (b) modeled by the database analysts, commonly in terms of entity types, properties and associations, so it is comprised of ideas or conceptualizations, it is not “concrete” yet and its representation requires constructs that are in lower levels of abstraction. The conceptual level is informally referred to as the *business rules* of a certain organization regarding its informational requirements. As an side, schemas of this kind are usually —though not necessarily— expressed via graphical devices like, e.g., entity-relationship diagrams to facilitate communication between the interested parties.
- The *internal* level has to do with how the DBMS of relevance stores the information in a concrete form; e.g., arrays, [pages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-page-layout.html), extents, files, records, fields, pointers, etc. This is the lower level  of abstraction since, to put it some way, the DBMS “saves” the information in “real” structures, so this may also be conceived as the *physical* level of the architecture but naming it in this way does not imply that there is a fourth level. It is worth to mention that there can be different sublevels of abstraction within the internal level itself, but that factor depends on the particular mechanisms used by the DBMS in question.

**Relational databases created on SQL DBMSs with respect to the ANSI/SPARC architecture**

When a practitioner uses a SQL platform (Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, Sybase ASE, PostgreSQL, etc.) to build a database using the mechanisms proposed by *the* [relational model](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685) by [Dr. E. F. Codd](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm):

- The *base* tables, columns, types (and domains when available) and constraints must reflect the characteristics of the conceptual schema (entity types, properties, associations, cardinalities) so that the data (in the shape of rows) remains consistent with it. The declarations made by means of a data sublanguage (e.g., SQL DDL) of the base tables, columns, types and constraints are instruments that formalize the conceptual schema, so they are considered *logical* constructs and, as such, they do not yet “tocuch” the physical level, they are still free from DBMS-specific concrete storage structures. Normalization, being a logical procedure, applies here, not at the conceptual schema.
- The views (i.e., *derived* tables that “combine” columns from one or more base tables or from other derived tables as well, typically by virtue of SQL DML operations involving JOINs) maintain a close correspondence to the *external* level, because they gather and provide the information requested or sent by the screens or windows of one or more application programs, just like the end-users see it.
- The [indexes](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree), [pages](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/), [extents](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-an-extent/), files<sup>1</sup>, [records](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/)<sup>2</sup>, fields<sup>3</sup>, partitions, [allocation maps](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-gam-sgam-pfs-and-other-allocation-maps/), and many other arrangements match the *internal* schema, since they are the “physical” structures utilized by a DBMS to store the information.

The SQL DBMS functions as a mediator (1) between the internal and the logical representations of the conceptual schemas, and (2) between the internal and external representations through connections via views.

**Notes**

---

<sub><sup>1, 2, 3</sup> Note how important it is to distinguish between (a) *files, records and fields* and (b) *tables, rows and columns* —or *relations, attributes and tuples*—, as they are elements that belong to distinct levels of abstraction and, hence, are susceptible of *very* different operations and treatments, having therefore very dissimilar impacts.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I understand the [three layers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-SPARC_Architecture) as:

1. Everything the user sees. Basically the relevant parts of the middle layer spiced with some views.
2. A logical or ER-model, this can be 3NF or similar - I would call this the relational model
3. Physical model, that means the specifics in the database

In current ER modelling, you would create a conceptual or logical model, capturing the requirements of users, then create a 3NF from it, to avoid inconsistencies and capture the correct multiplicities of the relationships (1:1, 1:N, N:M). Here you would also split entities, if necessary. For example split off addresses from customers, because you might need billing and shipping addresses. The last step would be to create the physical model, which considers indexes, surrogate keys, and careful denormalisation. This also includes considering advanced optimisations later on, like native types (e.g. double, int64, ...), types of indexes (btree vs bitmap, join indexes, etc.), special table layouts (row or column oriented, index organised tables, vertical or horizontal partitioning, inclusion of dependent rows). And this only mentions a few of the options that are available to the database designer in a current commercial database.

The access path usually is determined by the sql engine and its optimiser on the basis what is known about the data (statistics, quantity structure) and the indexes available and can be looked up in the execution plan for each SQL statement.

Answer (score -1):

that ANSI standard defines 3 different levels of describing the view+schematics of a database.
The "lowest" layer is independent of that - it is not part of the aforementioned standard - as it is the database itself.