# How Database Formats Files for Disk

Tags: postgresql, storage, datafile, disk-structures

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953638/how-is-mysql-data-stored-on-disk/16953724#16953724) outlines how MySQL organizes its database into files, but doesn't describe the structure of the files themselves.

I am wondering, at the physical level, how relational database management systems store their records in files. What the structure of the file is roughly, where the columns/values are (if it's just a CSV), and how it is traversed.

Comment: This is DBMS specific.  Please tag one

Comment: I tagged postgresql, but any DBMS is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is opportune to start pointing out that, in a *relational* database —as per [Dr. E.F. Codd](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm)— information is represented by means of one and only one structure, the *relation*, which is usually portrayed as a *table*.

The [relational model](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685) deals exclusively with aspects of the *logical* level of abstraction, so a table (an abstraction) is part of the logical level of a database (it is susceptible of undergoing logical operations, e.g., projections, joins, restrictions, etc.), so it is completely independent from the physical storage utlized by the *database management system* (DBMS for brevity) of use.

That being so, since the relational model has to do *solely* with logical-level aspects, it offers *physical data independence*, which sets DBMS (e.g., SQL platforms like IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc. —that although quite powerful, strictly speaking, are semi-relational, i.e., they do not comply fully with the stipulations of the relational framework—) free to (a) store at the *physical* level of abstraction in any way their developers/vendors deem convenient (b) the data represented via logical-level tables.

It is important to note that the physical-level storage can in turn be divided in distinct sub-levels of abstraction.

Therefore, the physical arrangements depend on the particular DBMS under consideration, hence they can vary from platform to platform.

Examples of physical structures utilized by different SQL platforms are detailed

- in the [*Storage Page Layout*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-page-layout.html) content from the PostgreSQL official documentation; and
- in the post entitled [*Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a record*](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/), regarding Microsoft SQL Server, by Paul Randal; and
- in SQLite's [*Database File Format*](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html) page.

In case you are interested, you may find of help [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200470/63644) to a question about some of the different levels of abstraction of a computerized information system.

Comment: We dont really care about the physical structure of the data on disk - that's an implementation detail. If you must know, you may download the source for postgresql or mysql and read the code - that will tell you how they store their data on disk.

Comment: (1) The OP is asking for details about how the DBMSs structure and store the data on disk. (2) Of course, everything at the physical level of abstraction is an implementation detail. (3) And, yes, I agree that reading the PostgreSQL, MySQL or Firebird source code directly can help to understand the arrangements of those specific DBMSs at the lowest sub-levels of abstraction within the physical level itself.